# Cardinality of $X \in \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ such that $x \neq y \in X \implies x-y\in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$

Tags: real-numbers, cardinals, irrational-numbers

The question is a follow up of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3878453/find-the-elements-of-this-set-x-is-a-subset-of-reals-such-that-for-each-disti).

Denote by $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ the power set of the reals and $A$ the subset of $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ consisting of the real subsets $X$ such that $x,y \in X$, $x \neq y$ implies $x-y \in \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q$.

Is there an uncountable element of $A$? Can such an element be *described explicitly* (I know that this question lacks precision)? What is the cardinality of $A$?

Comment: The cardinality of a $\Bbb{Q}$-basis of $\Bbb{R}$ (need choice ?) is clearly uncountable because otherwise $\Bbb{R}$ would be countable. Same for the cardinality of $\Bbb{R/Q}$, what you are asking. Intuitively each of them has the same cardinality as $\Bbb{R}$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a relation $\sim$ on $\Bbb R$ by $x\sim y$ iff $x-y\in\Bbb Q$. It’s easy to verify that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation. For $x\in\Bbb R$ let $[x]$ be the $\sim$-equivalence class of $x$. Then $[x]=x+\Bbb Q=\{x+q:q\in\Bbb Q\}$, so $[x]$ is countable. Let $\mathscr{C}=\{[x]:x\in\Bbb R\}$; $\Bbb R$ is uncountable, so $\mathscr{C}$ must also be uncountable. In fact

$$|\Bbb R|=|\mathscr{C}|\cdot|\Bbb Q|=\max\{|\mathscr{C}|,|\Bbb Q|\}=|\mathscr{C}|\,,$$

so we can go further and say that $|\mathscr{C}|=|\Bbb R|$. Now let $C$ contain exactly one member of each $\sim$-equivalence class; then $|C|=|\mathscr{C}|=|\Bbb R|$, and $C\in A$. Every subset of $C$ is also in $A$, so $A$ contains subsets of $\Bbb R$ of every possible size, i.e., every cardinality not exceeding $|\Bbb R|$.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the existence of set $C$ requires the Axiom of Choice.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan: Perhaps. Unless one is actually doing set theory, I see no more reason to point out the use of AC than to point out the use of any other axiom of ZFC, especially if one is doing topology or analysis.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - Hi Brian, If you have the time and don't mind, I have a question: why is it that I see the biconditional logical connective "if and only if" so much when defining an equivalence relation, e.g., "let $R \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ be an equivalence relation defined by $xRy$ if and only if $x=y$"? Additionally, can we use "if and only if" when defining relations that are not equivalence relations, e.g., "let $S \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ be a relation defined by $xSy$ if and only if $x \leq y$"?

Comment: @Taylor: In this context it’s not really anything to do with relations at all: ‘a topological space $X$ is *compact* if and only if each open cover of $X$ has a finite subcover’ defines the term *compact* (in a topological context) just your examples define the symbols $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $x\mathrel{S}y$ in some specific context. In each of these three examples we’re defining something by specifying under exactly what condition(s) it holds: $x\mathrel{R}y$ holds exactly when $x=y$, $x\mathrel{S}y$ holds exactly when $x\le y$, and $X$ is compact exactly when each of its open covers has a ...

Comment: ... finite subcover. If the defining condition holds, the statement $x\mathrel{R}y$ ($x\mathrel{S}y$, $X$ is compact, resp.) is true, and if the defining condition does not hold, the statement is not true. You’ll see *if and only if* when two assertions are declared to be equivalent, either by definition or as a consequence of other facts.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott - Gotcha! So the *if and only if* in the example "let $R \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ be a relation defined by $xRy$ if and only if $x=y$" has nothing to do with $R$ being an equivalence relation?

Comment: @TaylorRendon: Correct: it’s simply stating what property of a relation $R$ makes $R$ specifically an *equivalence* relation.